# Cocoa - Webview have request is nil when call createWebViewWithRequest

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I have a big problem with WebView in Cocoa.
My WebView loads a javascript that will open a new window in this WebView (not open in browser).

I call

```
[myWebView setUIDelegate: self]
```

to call the createWebViewWithRequest:withRequest:

In the createWebViewWithRequest, I load the request, but the request is nil. I don't know why and am stuck here.

```
- (WebView*)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    [[sender mainFrame]loadRequest:request];
    return sender;
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270458/cocoa-webkit-having-window-open-javascript-links-opening-in-an-instance-of

Comment: I try this link before, but it doesn't with me. The webview doesn't open new window in webview. Maybe my question is not clear. I will update it.

Comment: A response on that question mentions also that the request in CreateWebViewWithRequest is nil cause of a bug in WebKit.

Answer (score 5):

Passing a nil request here was an [intentional change in WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/75349).

Maybe you can change your JavaScript to use ...

```
<a target=_blank href="http://www.example.com/">
```

... instead of `window.open()`?

If you do that you can use the

[`-webView:decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:request:newFrameName:decisionListener:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:request:newFrameName:decisionListener:)

method of `WebPolicyDelegate` to get the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

```
[[sender mainFrame]loadRequest:request];
```